# Is MySQL compatible with EF Core 2.0?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, gcloud

Do you have any idea about that?

I need to know if MySQL is compatible with EF Core 2.0. I have a **.Net Core Web Api project** and I am using **local MS SQL Server database**.

Now I need to open my database to the world. To achieve that I am planing to use **Azure** or **Gcloud**, but they use **MySQL**. My other choice is **MS SQL Server** on *virtual machine*. Please check the following website on the MySQL EF Core Database Provider, particularly the comments section:
.

[From Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/mysql/)

Comment: Did you even try to Google this?

Comment: Just the link you provide says there is MySQL database provider, but it is in pre-release. So yes, you can connect to MySQL from Core 2.0.

Comment: Microsoft Azure supports Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is.

I am successfully using MariaDB (fork of MySQL) with the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql MySQL provider and EF Core 2.

See here: https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/master/src/FilterLists.Data/FilterLists.Data.csproj